# In the shell, what is “ 2>&1 &”?

Tags: shell, sh

I understand that 2>&1 sends both stout and sterr to one file. But what does an `&` in the end means?

```
2>&1 &
#    ^ this one
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells bash to run the job in the background, returning an interactive terminal to the user (see also [here](http://hacktux.com/bash/ampersand)). You can get the job back to the foreground by entering

```
fg
```

If you want to run multiple commands in the background from a single command line statement, you need to encapsulate them in parentheses, e.g.

```
(cmd1 &); (cmd2 &);
```

If you would like to execute multiple commands together as one background process, you can group them using braces:

```
({ subcmd11; subcmd12; } &); ( { subcmd21; subcmd22; } &);
```

Please note that the braces need to be followed by a whitespace and that the list of commands inside braces must be terminated by a semicolon (regular parentheses do not have these limitations, but they create an additional subshell). For a good overview of the two grouping styles, check this [reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html).

Comment: The link doesn't work, but yes thankyou. I have another issue, I am trying to run multiple commands like these in a shell script. but its complaining about a syntax error for the semi-colon after & ? Is it not possible?

Comment: Ok Example: set -e;sudo service nginx start; QUEUE=* bundle exec rake environment resque:work >>/home/jobs/log/resque.log 2>&1 &;
rake resque:scheduler >>/home/jobs/log/resque-scheduler.log 2>&1 &